# How to install a proof-of-work proxy server on raspberry pi 3B

Tags: raspberry-pi3, caddy, caddyfile, iota

I am trying to install a proof-of-work proxy server from the link: https://docs.iota.org/docs/node-software/0.1/iri/how-to-guides/install-a-pow-proxy on Raspberry Pi 3B. However, when I try to build an executable file at step 4, I get the following error:

> main.go:22:8: cannot find package
>   "github.com/mholt/caddy/caddy/caddymain" in any of:
>
> /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/mholt/caddy/caddy/caddymain (from $GOROOT )
>
> /home/pi/go/src/github.com/mholt/caddy/caddy/caddymain (from $GOPATH)

Comment: The caddy repo moved to https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy -- make sure you follow the readme instructions there to build Caddy.

Comment: can you please explain more how should I do it in the context of iotacaddy?